# onclick on span using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<a title="Prev" data-event="click" data-handler="prev" class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all">
       <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span>
   </a>
```

I need to change 'Prev' once click on span using jquery.

This is my code:

```
$(".ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w").click(function(){ 
    $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w").html('«');         
});
```

But it does not work, why?

Answer (score 9):

Maybe your code is executed too early. And your html element just doesn't exist when your code is executed. So `$(".ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w")` is just empty.

You can use this :

```
$("body").on('click', ".ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w", function(){ 
    $(this).html('«');         
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Give your `<span>` a class:

```
<a title="Prev" data-event="click" data-handler="prev" class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all">
       <span class="prevSpan ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span></a>
```

and then use it via jQuery:

```
$(".prevSpan").text("«");
```

You need a eventhandler for the click event, use `.on()`
finally the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.prevSpan').on('click',function(){
    $(".prevSpan").text("«");
  });
});
```

Documentation for the .on() eventhandler http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ui-icon .ui-icon-circle-triangle-w").click(function(){ 
    $(this).html('«');         
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.